# example project for Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I have learned and tried the basic examples from sites like  www.mkyong.com ,krams915.blogspot.com .

Now i want to try building some applications using Spring,hibernate. I am looking for some project examples which i can refer.

I searched google for this , but couldn't find one

Can anyone please suggest?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search [GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=spring+hibernate&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&language=Java), [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/repo/all/followers?name=spring+hibernate) or [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/directory/language%3ajava/os%3awindows/freshness%3arecently-updated/?q=spring%20hibernate). There is also a "semi-official" sample app [PetClinic](http://static.springsource.org/docs/petclinic.html) developed by SpringSource.